# How do I debug returned AJAX data in the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that makes an AJAX request and returns some data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#test").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: "",
                data: { "value": $("#test").val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data){
                   $("div#return").text(data)
                }
            });
    });
});
```

When this is displayed it's displayed as `[object Object]`. I'd like to access it in the console but when I load the console and type `data` it tells me `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined(...)`

The data is returned from my Django view and `data` is a JSON object as so:

```
    payload = {
        'main': {
            "title": "Jim",
            "description": "I am cool"
        }
    }

    return JsonResponse(payload, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Set a break point on the line `$("div#return").text(data)` and then you should be able to examine it.

Comment: The object in the `data` variable is coerced to a string when you give it to the `text()` method, instead use `console.log(data)` to see the value it contains.

Comment: Also, what did you expect it to display? `[object Object]` is the default `toString` for an object. If you wanted, for example, the title, then just do `$("div#return").text(data.main.title)`

Comment: @Nanor, did it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: `console.dir` might be more helpful, depending on the browser.

Comment: @MattBurland Or `console.info('Retrieved from %s: %O', url, data);`

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add a break point:

```
success: function(data){
  debugger;
}
```